# How to tell which postgres queries are causing sequence scans

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I'm reviewing my pg_stat_all_tables stats and am seeing several large tables are generating a bunch of table scans. Are there any queries I can run to determine which queries are causing these sequence scans?

Comment: I don't think there are any system views for that. But you could use auto explain and the search the logfiles: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no retroactive way to do so, and the stats collector doesn't associate the stats counters with particular statements.

The `pg_stat_statements` extension will help you collect statement information, and the `auto_explain` module will help collect plan information.